# Android table row onClickListener

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, onclicklistener

I am having some problems when trying to trigger events on table layout in Android. These are the codes I used to populate the table layout dynamically:

```
private void BuildTable() {
    try {
        DatabaseAdapter mDbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(Category.this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        CategoryController cc = new CategoryController(mDbHelper.open());
        Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(cc.getAllCat(), null);

        if (mCur.getCount() != 0) {
            if (mCur.moveToFirst()) {
                // Setting table header
                TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
                row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                do {
                    int cols = mCur.getColumnCount();
                    row = new TableRow(this);

                    for (int j = 1; j < cols; j++) {
                        // Dynamically load data fetch from database
                        // into table layout
                        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                        tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        tv.setPadding(5, 5, 10, 5);
                        tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                        tv.setText(mCur.getString(j));
                        row.addView(tv);
                        row.setId(j);
                    }

                    row.setClickable(true);

                    row.setOnClickListener(tablerowOnClickListener);
                    table_layout.addView(row);
                } while (mCur.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        throw mSQLException;
    }
}
```

And here is my table row onClickListener:

```
private OnClickListener tablerowOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Highlight selected row
        v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));
        final int k = v.getId();
        Toast.makeText(Category.this, Integer.toString(k),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

My problem is when I highlighted certain row and I select another row again, the previous highlighted row remains the same highlighted background color. I wonder how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Iterate over all the rows in the TableLayout, highlighting the one clicked, and setting the others to the regular color.

Comment: @MikeM. Would you mind to provide me some example?

Comment: Sure thing. Gimme a minute; I'm on a mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided `table_layout` is in the same scope as `tablerowOnClickListener`, change the Listener as follows:

```
private OnClickListener tablerowOnClickListener = new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //Highlight selected row
        for (int i = 0; i < table_layout.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            View row = table_layout.getChildAt(i);
            if (row == v)
            {
                row.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));
            }
            else
            {
                //Change this to your normal background color.
                row.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
            }
        }
        //...
    }
};
```